# Not able to shutdown jupyter notebook from anacondaprompt

Tags: jupyter-notebook, miniconda

So I just started using `jupyter notebooks`. I have installed something called `mini conda` and followed a walkthrough which guided me through installing jupyter notebooks. However, after finishing my work, I tried to go to the `miniconda prompt` and pressed `Ctrl+C` to close the which is supposed be shutting the notebook but it doesn't seem to be working. I have had people suggest me to press `Ctrl+C` twice but that doesn't get the job done as well. I'm not able to interact with the terminal after using the command that opens the jupyter notebook. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jupyter notebook list
```

Which should give you an output like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=ef12021898c435f865ec706de98632 ...
```

Once you have retrieved your port number:

```
jupyter notebook stop 8888 # replace 8888 by your port number here
```

Comment: I do this after I type `jupyter notebook` right? If that is the case, I'm not to type or do anything in the terminal after my jupyter notebook opens